# Setting opacity of each image drawn on canvas with imagemagick

Tags: imagemagick, transparency, opacity

I have the command below which takes multiple image sources and draw it onto 1 output.png file.

```html
Convert img1.jpg -resize 1000x1000! 
-draw "image over 169,555 875,109 'img1.png'"  
-draw "image over 29,55 375,209 'img2.png'"
-draw "image over 129,525 15,29 'img3.png'"
png24:output.png
```

Is there a way to set the opacity of each of the images being drawn? where some might have opacity of 60% , while others have 100%

I tried this but doesn't work:

```html
Convert img1.jpg -resize 1000x1000! 
\( -alpha set -channel A -evaluate set 60% \) -draw "image over 169,555 875,109 'img1.png'"  
\( -alpha set -channel A -evaluate set 100% \) -draw "image over 29,55 375,209 'img2.png'"
\( -alpha set -channel A -evaluate set 90% \) -draw "image over 129,525 15,29 'img3.png'"
png24:output.png
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I *think* you want something like this...

```
convert img1.jpg -resize 1000x1000!  \
\( img1.png -alpha set -channel A -evaluate set  60% -resize 707x447 \) -geometry +169+109 -composite \
\( img2.png -alpha set -channel A -evaluate set 100% -resize 347x155 \) -geometry +29+55   -composite \
\( img3.png -alpha set -channel A -evaluate set  90% -resize 115x497 \) -geometry +15+29   -composite \
png24:output.png
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer Mark. While this did do the trick for opacity, but having problems with images with transparent background, instead of 'blank' transparent background, it's showing weird scruffs/marks. eg. http://s7.postimg.org/5qvk273i3/trans.jpg

Comment: Can you make *all* the images available please? And, hopefully, one "correct" output image?

Comment: this is the complete image generated. http://postimg.org/image/5yawxkh2n/

and the command was 

convert img/15/312/aagfsv/555.jpg -resize 1160x1365! \( img/15/312/aagfsv/t9yc.png -alpha set -channel A -evaluate set  100% -resize 391x374  \) +channel -geometry +418+67 -composite  \( img/15/312/aagfsv/eaaa.png -alpha set -channel A -evaluate set  80% -resize 389x372  \) +channel -geometry +433+475 -composite  \( img/15/312/aagfsv/67xi.png -alpha set -channel A -evaluate set  60% -resize 387x370  \) +channel -geometry +435+896 -composite  png24:img/15/312/aagfsv/xx.png